# Show free space at the begining and the end of a text inside a span

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup to show a span with `background-color : lightgrey` and `color : darkgrey` :--

```
<span class="singleNews__content__info__label">Business News</span>


.singleNews__content__info__label{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    color: #5f5f5f;
    text-align: center;}
```

here is the result:-

[image]

but i am trying to get this result where there will be some free space at the beginning and at the end of the text:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With padding-left and padding-right you can add space before and after the word. Also with -top and -bottom you can add on the y-direction space.

```css
.paddTheSpan {
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
.singleNews__content__info__label{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    color: #5f5f5f;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="singleNews__content__info__label paddTheSpan">Business News</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add padding to your css:

```
.singleNews__content__info__label{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    color: #5f5f5f;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple question that you can achieve answer by putting in some effort. You have to use [box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) to apply spacing on elements using **Margin & Padding**.

```css
.singleNews__content__info__label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  color: #5f5f5f;
  text-align: center;
  /* HERE */
  padding: 10px 20px
}
```

```html
<span class="singleNews__content__info__label">Business News</span>
```